# How to make real-time pvp game where both players perceive in-game time normally while actual relative time-flow speed between them is different?

Tags: time, game-physics, game-development, multiplayer, real-time-multiplayer

I was thinking about making a real-time (not tour-like) PvP game where both players among other attributes would have 'speed' attribute that would define their movement and attack speed.

But because the speed can be very fast (for example 50 attacks within one second), too high speed would make it difficult for players to fully utilize it (as they would have very hard time reacting on time on the events in the fight and instead of definite advantage the would struggle with controlling their characters).

Therefore the best solution would be changing time flow speed between players - so for faster players the in-game time would flow slower comparing to players with slower speed.

Ideally I would like to make it like the player with higher speed sees themselves in normal speed and their opponent seems slowed down while players with slower speed would see themselves in normal speed while their opponent seems abnormally fast.

And here I encounter the problem.

While implementing such mechanics in single player games (player vs AI) wouldn't be difficult,
I can't find the way to do that for PvP. The time flow for both players in their real life is obviously the same which kinda leads to paradoxes if we assume different time flow in in-game world.

One way could be making the player with slower speed perceiving the slow motion effect while the opponent moves normally - but it won't be realistic (especially if there are more than 2 players - because then only fastest player moves normally and all other players on ENTIRE battlefield experience being more or less slowed down just because there is one fast guy - feels like killing the purpose).

So my question is.. is there any way to do this or it is really entirely impossible to achieve the effect?

Thank you in advance for help! <3

Comment: This probably fits better in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/, that said, I don't know if this ever being tried, every slowdown effect in singleplayer are usually disabled entirely in multiplayer

Comment: Ok, will ask there also :)